# How to remove editinng mode by touching on tableview?

Tags: iphone

If you click on the Edit button, you see the red stop signs. How to remove this when user touch on the tableview or tableview cell?

Please help me for this 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use `setEditing` method of `UITableView`.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate
```

Like below

```
[myTableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop editing on cell selection then use this method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

       [myTableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
}
```